# Android Data Fetch From Database Not Working (php + json + mysql)

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

***Although I know that this question has already been posted on stack overflow many times, but I have tried all solutions and nothing worked for me.***

I am trying to display data in List View. Data is stored in the json format and while fetching data it seems like android is not reading the JSON Array and hence data is not coming up in List View and it remains empty.

Java file:

```
public class ReadResult extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ResultFetch;
private static String url_readResult = "http://10.0.2.2/Result-Viewer/php/ReadData.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SCORE = "Score";
private static final String TAG_SEMESTER = "Semester";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
JSONArray products = null;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_result);
    list = (ListView) getListView();
    ResultFetch = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new LoadResult().execute();
}

class LoadResult extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadResult.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Result. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_readResult, "GET",
                param);


        Log.d("Result: ", json.toString());
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                products = object.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Semester = c.getString(TAG_SEMESTER);
                    String Score = c.getString(TAG_SCORE);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_SEMESTER, Semester);
                    map.put(TAG_SCORE, Score);
                    ResultFetch.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 toast.show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ReadResult.this,
                        ResultFetch, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                TAG_SEMESTER, TAG_SCORE }, new int[] {
                                R.id.semester, R.id.score });

                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

php file :

```
<?php
session_start();
$cid = $_SESSION["cid"];
$rno = $_SESSION["rno"];
$response = array();

$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=result','root' ,'');
$result=$conn->query("Select * from $cid where RegistrationNumber =     '$rno'");

if($result->rowcount()>0)
{
$response["products"] = array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
$product["Semester"] = $row["Semester"];
$product["Score"] = $row["Score"];
$response["success"] = 1;
array_push($response["products"], $product);
echo json_encode($response);
}
}
else
{
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No record found.";
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I have passed the cid,rno and password through sign in page  and the following is the json output generated by running read data page.

json output :

```
{"products":[{"Semester":"0","Score":"0"}],"success":1}
```

Comment: so what you done to debug this? did you check what's arriving in android? maybe your php is spitting out warnings, corrupting the json.

Comment: I am reaching upto the progress bar in Read result page but after that nothing works. I am getting success=1 in log file for the result's page.After that I get an get warning/error:no value for products.

Comment: Have you considered using Gson to map your json to a Java object? It would achieve what you are trying to do in just a few lines.

Comment: @IvanWooll I am not familiar with Gson. Can you provide me the code for the same if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got a comment on your code that might help. The following line is useless

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json.toString());
```

as you can just use `json` as your `JSONObject` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Sorry!  But this did'nt worked out for me. Still getting no values in list.

Comment: @SarthakGarg Does `success` equal 1 or 0?

Comment: the  value of success = 1

Answer (score 0):

In reply to a comment from Sarthak Garg I'm posting an example here of converting a String response to a Java object using Gson.

I'd personally take a different approach to making a call to your web service than you are but that's outside the scope of this discussion so I'll just say what I would do given your existing code sample.

The following line from your code sample gives you a json object which can easily be converted to a String.

```
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_readResult, "GET",param);
String myString = json.toString();
```

What Gson does for you is all of the tedious work of parsing the json and extracting the various parts you need from it. To understand the full capabilities of Gson you'll need to do some Googling, the sample I give you here is just one thing you can do with it.

What this sample does is creates a new Gson instance and then uses that instance to convert your json String to a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Think of the YourPojo class as a template which you give to Gson to use in order to tell it what the incloming json will look like and what you'd like the resulting object to look like.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(myString, YourPojo.class);
```

The only extra work you have to do here is create the YourPojo class and thankfully there are tools out there which can help with that, e.g. [this one](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

These tools will take a json sample you provide it with and generate a Pojo class or classes for you. All you need do is supply the class name.

If you've implemented this successfully you'll be able to call methods like `pojo.getProducts()` and `pojo.getSuccess()` on your pojo object.