# get string from php json encode to android target api23+

Tags: php, android, json, httpurlconnection, jsonreader

I have a php file that generates data that must take to Android. 
This is the file output .php

```
[{"item":"1","title":"Title of one","link":"qwerty1234"},{"item":"2","title":"Title of two","link":"qwerty1234"},{"item":"3","title":"Title of three","link":"qwerty1234"}]
```

Now there have been changes with the class apache: [Link here](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Looking around I find several guides on the old method but I wanted to use the new one since my app is the targetSdkVersion 23.
I think this is the new method with JsonReader and HttpURLConnection.

I tried but I can not make it work or understand how to handle it.

So I ask, how do I take the strings from php page that creates? (example: title and link)

Comment: Where's the code you've tried? If we can't see what's generating errors or some code, we don't know where to start to help.

Comment: Like this (java file)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403892/android-data-fetch-from-database-not-working-php-json-mysql

Comment: try this website https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html there is an updated an simple way, if it doesn't work just tell me and i'll give you a working code i have in one of my apps

Comment: Thanks Marco, I had already seen the link. I'm trying with this and I do not work.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: @marcoFSN You can post the code that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this.

it's working for me.

```
    String url = "someurl.php";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);

        String error = jsonObject.getString("item1");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in this case i was using GSON to later parse the response but you can parse it as you wish.

this is a snippet of code that i can provide, if you need more help or if some dependencies are missing please tell me so i can point you in  the right direction.

have a look at this tutorial for more help

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

if you need a webservice PHP framework, take a look at this

http://www.slimframework.com/

it's very easy to use and ligthweight framework so you can use it as a service to send and recieve info from your server

hope it helps, feel free to ask if you need any more help

cheers